# ILDASM in x64 folder

Tags: .net, cil, il

I have been using ildasm.exe (to view .NET assemblies) from the location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin

But, there is another ildasm.exe in a subfolder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64

Is there any difference between the two exe's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version in the x64 directory is compiled as 64-bit application. This may be useful in theory if disassembling a very large IL file, but in practice the virtual memory limits are hard to reach. There's no difference in functionality.